# Execute FitNesse RestFixture Tests from commandline

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, fitnesse, restfixture

I like to execute the tests which uses the RestFixture from the commandline. I'm also planning to integrate the same in the TFS Build Configuration via Powershell script.
[image]

Comment: Good for you - is there an actual question in here?

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish this. That is the question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing a jUnit class annotated to be run with the FitNesseRunner, and indicating Suite/Test to be run. Then you can use either Maven or Ant to run that test from the command line (I believe TFS has out of the box support to run Maven, without the need for any Powershell).

Sample jUnit test, running FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir(".")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("./build/fitnesse-results")
public class FitNesseRunnerTest {
}
```

Comment: I like to run the same in the command line. I'm testing the API's which eventually does a check on the API stored by doing a fiddler capture of all the API. Which avoids load on the API server.